# String conversion macro

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I must store some strings with a custom encoding (let's say A->0, B->1, etc.).

I'd like to be able to declare them as :

```
u8 string1[] = ENCODE("ABC");
```

rather than :

```
u8 string1[] = {0, 1, 2};
```

so ENCODE(s) is a macro that should develop as a byte array representing the encoded string (and while I'm at it, it should add a string terminator value) (here u8 is an alias for unsigned char).

I have absolutely no idea is this is feasible using the C preprocessor. But I'd be surprised.

Comment: I't only feasible as a macro, if the macro calls a function to do the transformation.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear : I WANT it to be a macro.
ENCODE("ABC") must develop into {0, 1, 2};

Comment: And you CAN'T have it implemented as a pure macro. The arrays containing the literal string `"ABC"` doesn't really exist at the time when the preprocessor is executed. [This translation phase reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases) might be helpful. The preprocessor runs in step 4 while the actual compilation (which includes the actual handling of string literals and their storage) is handled in phase 7.

Comment: The C preprocessor simply does not support such stuff like decomposing string literals. You could, however, write e. g. a python script doing this stuff and run it as pre-build step before the preprocessor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I afraid you cant. The preprocessor as the name states does something with the file before the actual compilation. It does not know anything about arrays, strings etc.

Comment: But ENCODE doesn't have to know about those things, as far I can tell...

Everything can be done before actual compilation...

Comment: @T.Tournesol In any case what you want is impossible in C. If you could switch to C++, you could use `constexpr` functions. Otherwise you're out of luck.

Comment: There is really no reason to hardcode either, if the character is `A-Z`, simply subtract `'A'`, if `a-z`, simply subtract `'a'` (or `'a' + 26` to make lowercase `26-52`).

Comment: Ok, sorry, I'm just confused on where your strings are coming from. I was thinking a simple function, but if that won't work, you are left hardcoding.

Answer (score -1):

A macro cannot access the individual characters of a string.

As an added complication, if `string1` is supposed to have *static* storage duration (global, `static` in a function, etc...), you cannot even use a string literal, because the integer values in initializers need to be *integer constant expressions*.

For a non-static initializer you *could* use some kind of an expression that expands to a nested `? :`, but it would be just as awful - and easily replaced by a function.

---

You *can* use individual characters and a variable argument macro.